# Issue with freeing pointer field in a C++ map value

Tags: c++, dictionary, free

I have a structure:

`typedef struct
{
    char *ptr;
} A;`

And a map

```
typedef std::map<std::wstring, A> myMap;
```

I have allocated memory for the ptr field using malloc while filling up the map.
To prevent memory leaks while clearing the map, I have the following code (actualMap is the actual map that I have to clear):

```
for (myMap::iterator iter = actualMap.begin(); iter != actualMap.end(); ++iter)
{
    Free((iter->second).ptr);
}
actualMap.clear();
```

However, when I start the application normally, I'm getting an exception while Free is being executed. This exception is not being generated when I start the application directly via VS2010.
Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Free? with uppercase F ?

Comment: Does each struct A you're putting in the map *own* the underlying char pointer it contains? If not, then you should not be deleting it. And if this really is all that is in that struct *and* you're dynamically allocating them per inserted instance, is there *any* good reason you're *not* using `std::string` as your map value-class?

Comment: Why don't you use new/delete unstead of malloc/free ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, I was actually copying data into this ptr field from another char * (and vice versa), hence had kept it as of the same type.

Comment: @QuentinC, please read above comment.

Comment: You said you were "actually copying data into this ptr field from another `char *`. As in, allocating a new buffer and men/str-cpying your original into the one now stored in your `A`? or are you just putting the pointer into the structure? I hope its obvious why I ask. If you don't actually own the struct definition of `A` you may be limited as far as options are concerned. As written, there is nothing wrong with your mechanic for cleaning out  **valid** allocated data pointed to by your map objects, but I still question the origin and ownership of them. it sounds like they're free'd already.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I use malloc and copy data into the ptr field from the source char *. When I attach the process to VS after receiving the exception, I see that the ptr field contains valid data.

Comment: @user1157812 interesting. what, if that is the case, does the stack trace look like for that exception. The first half-dozen or so lines should be sufficient if you could post them into the question as an addendum (pretty VS will let you cut-paste them, but you may need to clean them up to make them presentable, in code-form please for readability. Also, your real `struct A` has no destructors and such, correct? As I said, provided the only valid pointers to that data are *in the map* this should not be an issue. your problem is likely somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm sorry but the code is proprietary, so I can't paste the trace here. But thanks for mentioning the std::string approach, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use C++ std::string instead of raw pointer

```
struct A
{ 
  std::wstring data;
};

std::map<std::wstring, A> myMap;

actualMap.clear();
```

A only has one pointer which points to string, so myMap can be:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> myMap;
```

Comment: Thanks. This was just a sample structure, it contains some other fields as well. I had stripped it down to show only relevant info. The suggestion looks good, although I'm still not sure as to what's wrong with the specified code. If that can be found out, it would be great.

Comment: @billz... Pedantically, this isn't the answer, but I hadn't thought of this approach, and it works pretty well (apart from being better!). Hence marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The other way is to use smart pointer to replace your raw pointer, should make much change to your code and it deallocates memory for you.